# Ubuntu 16.04 software center not working

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, software-center

Just installed the UBUNTU 16.04 LTS. I just noticed that the software center is not working. I did installed the older version of it (`sudo apt-get install software-center`) but I want the new software center.

How can I install the new version of the software center?

Comment: What do you get when you type `gnome-software` in a terminal ?

Comment: (gnome-software:26239): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: There was a bug in 16.04. Just update the system fully.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Type the following in the terminal in order to update `gnome-software`, which should fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade gnome-software
```

You can also update using the graphical update manager, which will do the same thing.

(The version of `gnome-software` shipped with Ubuntu had a bug which meant that it sometimes wouldn't start, which was fixed in a update)

Comment: Still not working... I got this:  **gnome-software is already the newest version (3.20.1+git20160426.1.a976144-ubuntu-xenial-0ubuntu1).* * and then, when I type _gnome-software_ I get the same message as before...

Comment: @Gabs, try reinstalling it with `sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software && 
sudo apt-get install gnome-software`, and restarting your computer - does that fix it ?

Comment: Yes, it is ok now, but I get this warning message: *(gnome-software:2079): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*...

Comment: @Gabs, I think you can ignore the warning message if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I looked on the dashboard and had two Ubuntu Software programs installed. Deleted the old one (Ubuntu Software Center). That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared on clean installation of 16.04, was fixed, and re-appeared. While it is difficult to replicate the issue and to analyze conditions, there was a fortunate remedy.

Using Synaptic Package Manager, go to **Menu > Edit > Fix Broken Packages**, mark identified packages for fix and upgrade, and let it apply.

Then restart the computer.