# Ubuntu Restricted Extras Won't Work

Tags: software-center, flash

Ok, so, I installed Ubuntu-Restricted-Extras on Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS. I have all the updates. I used the terminal to install it because I couldn't find it in Ubuntu Software. But what I want to know is the Ubuntu Software Center, is Ubuntu Software and Ubuntu Software Center the same thing? Because if they are there is something wrong with mine, I can't install things like preload at all and flash player won't work (has it been removed?). In the Ubuntu Software app there are hardly any programs, and again, nothing like preload or Ubuntu restricted extras. Help me I am going bloody insane.

Comment: These packages ? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-restricted-extras ? It is in multiverse - https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository . If that repo is enabled, and you still have a problem, please provide additional information.

Comment: By design Ubuntu Software only handles applications with a graphical user interface. And [Flash works](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution?

I don't think Ubuntu Restricted Extras Won't Work.

I think the problem is 'Ubuntu Software [Center]'. Maybe the following link (within AskUbuntu) can help you solve that problem.

[Ubuntu 16.04 software center not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783938/ubuntu-16-04-software-center-not-working)

### Workarounds

But there are work-arounds.

- Continue to use the command line tools,

  to keep Ubuntu up to date

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt full-upgrade
  ```

  to keep Ubuntu clean (remove unnecessary program packages)

  ```
  sudo apt autoremove
  sudo apt autoclean
  sudo apt clean
  ```

  to install a new program package `program-package`

  ```
  sudo apt install program-package
  ```
- Use the Synaptic Package Manager

  Install it

  ```
  sudo apt install synaptic
  ```

  and start it from 'Dash', after clicking on the Ubuntu icon at the top left corner and typing `syn`.

  There is a learning curve, but Synaptic is reliable and powerful. Later on, when 'Ubuntu Software' starts working again, you might stay with Synaptic, because you know it and like it :-)

  [image]

Comment: thank you, I don't know what is happening with Ubuntu software center but synaptic works very well : )

Comment: @Shane.D, You are welcome :-)