# Ubuntu Software does not work

Tags: software-center

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. the Ubuntu Software does not work. 
I used a command

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

It updated my Ubuntu Software Center but still it does not work.I cannot open it.

Comment: Which one of desktop environment you use?

Comment: Maybe you will be happy with the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020754/ubuntu-restricted-extras-wont-work/1020761?s=1|8.5948#1020761)