# Installed programes is not lising in software center ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-center

I am trying to have an overall look of the programs installed on my computer, but the software center is not able to load them. I tried this solution [`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade gnome-software`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783938/ubuntu-16-04-software-center-not-working) I got the following output, Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem.

```
Hit:1 http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
Ign:2 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                         
Get:3 http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:4 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu xenial Release                           
Get:5 http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Fetched 216 kB in 1s (199 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-software is already the newest version (3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.11).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

[image]
Any solution available for this problem??

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to do this by using **only** the Software Center and **not** by using the command line with something simple like `dpkg --get-selections | grep "\sinstall" | awk ' { print $1 } '> ~/Desktop/installed-software.txt`? In other words, you want a fix to get the Software Center to work as it should?

Comment: @DKBose u r right .... i have a lot of other options, but want to have a working software center......